# Ignore a column when using `.changed?` in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to use the `.changed?` method to check if a record has changed. The problem is that one of the fields will always be different. I would like to ignore the field. Something like:

```
record.changed?.except(:field_to_ignore)
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

`ActiveModel::Dirty` gives you a list of all the attributes that have changed via the `changed` method. So you could do something like

```
record.changed.reject { |attr| attr == 'field_to_ignore' }.size > 0
```

Read more about `changed` method [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-changed)

Comment: `record.changed_attributes.except('field_to_ignore').any?` is a bit more concise and idiomatic

Answer (score 0):

EDITED

A simple solution to this is to use the same `changed?` functionality from `ActiveModel::Dirty`, so let's say that the attribute you don't want to take into account is `x`, with that said you can do something like this:

```rb
atttibutes_changed = record.changed_attributes.keys
atttibutes_changed.size > 1 || !atttibutes_changed.include?('x')
```

The above condition means: if more than one attribute changed or in case one changed need to be different from `x`. `changed_attributes` returns a hash with all the attributes that changed and his values (before change).

Comment: From what I understand, this is not correct. The question was to ignore the field, meaning its changes should not have any affect. As per your solution, if 2 fields changed, and the ignored field was one of them, the other change will also be ignored.

Comment: agreed I will edit my answer with a proper solution thx @Anuj

Comment: Thanks. That's a clever answer @r4cc00n, though a bit tough to read :)